# Ambient dependency injection through static service locator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, service-locator

After some googling I found some debates about whether constructor injection or property/field injection is better, but there is yet another alternative that strikes me as more beneficial.

In most programming environments, there is something called "the call context", which is information implicitly passed from caller to callee.

Sometimes this context is simply thread-local storage, sometimes, in the case of cross-thread asynchronous programming, it's more complex than that.

In any case, such contexts store information such as culture, user, or, for web applications, the current request.

These types of information are rarely carried around explicitly but accessed through global methods that are accessing said contexts.

In the use case of dependency injection, this means a static/global form of service locator (my example is in C#):

```
public static Sl
{
    public static Dependency Get<Dependency>();

    public static IDisposable Push<Dependency>(Dependency dependency);
}
```

The usage would be:

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
    Sl.Get<Dependency>().UseItSomehow();
}
```

To call `SomeFunction`, the dependency can be set or changed for the callees like this:

```
using (Sl.Push<SomeDependency>(someImplementation)
{
    SomeFunction();
}
```

I think this pattern superior to other types of dependency injection *in those cases where a dependency is uniformly required for a large part of a larger call subtree*.

For example, a repository, logger or configuration interface is rarely required only for a single function, but also for all its subsequent nested calls.

Especially with contructor injection this leads to some clutter that can be completely avoided: `SomeFunction` above can call other functions that will get the dependency automatically. It can also change the dependency in those cases where it actually is necessary.

I want to address some of the concerns I think I read somewhere, and my question would then be if anyone can think of others.

- There's a dependency on `Sl`

  This strikes me as a fundamentalist's objection. Most software also depend on integers, strings and lists, without such things being properly abstracted away and passed around with proper respect to the pure Church of Dependency Injection. Clearly *some* low-level things one needs to depend on directly - hopefully they are well-designed and ideally they reside in the runtime library of the respective language. If not, they may still be the lesser evil.
- Required dependencies should be explicit

  The only really explicit form of DI is contructor injection or passing dependencies directy in method calls. Unfortunately, this is also the most verbose and unflexible way of doing it. Dependencies that are added later change constructor or method signatures, requiring a refactoring of potentially several layers of function calls that do nothing but passing down objects verbatim. In static languages, this is tedious. In dynamic ones, it's even a source of bugs.

  Furthermore, if the dependency is required, the respective feature will fail whenever it's used anyway, making it very likely that a missing-dependency bug won't accidentally go to production.

  So ideally, yes, required dependencies should be explicit. But there's always a tradeoff, and am I really the only one who thinks that the constructor injection folk don't have their priorities straight?
- One shouldn't rely on magic

  Call contexts and thread-statics are not magic, they are merely advanced and perhaps more technical than what is covered in your typical programming course at university.

  Also, the implementation is hidden behind the static service locator. Users don't have to know how it works to use it.

Besides this, there's also a strange hypocrisy among DI-fans. Take ASP.NET Core, for example: These guys literally force a DI-paradigm on their users. The result is a design that makes realizing existing dependencies particularly difficult. It's as if they are mocking themselves.

Consider how they allow binding certain configuration for outgoing web requests, such as authentication or setting some custom headers, to the code that is using it: You first do the configuration code (`HttpClient` and `HttpClientFactory`) and put them in a global service container. Then whereever the client is needed, it's fished out of the container. That means that if the configuration code is missing, everything will still compile and you won't notice until runtime.

And what if you have different configurations for different use points? ASP.NET Core's solution: Associate the specially configured `HttpClientFactory`s with magic strings and use those magic strings to fish out the correct one where it's needed!

Are you kidding me? What's going on here?

Dependencies used to be *more* explicit before this insanity was sweeping the minds of coders.

I'm now asked to make tedious finger excerises (ctor injection) and then throw those types all in one global container with no compile time checking for correct composability whatsoever.

So my question: Are there any legitimate, real-world reasons why DI with a static/global service locator would be bad, or am I correct in concluding that it is a sensible way to deal with this unfortunate craziness?

Comment: To which class does `SomeFunction()` belong? Why can't that class provide the context of `SomeFunction()` and provide the dependencies in member variables (injected, for example, through its constructor)?

Comment: "For example, a repository, logger or configuration interface is rarely required only for a single function, but also for all its subsequent nested calls." <- I think this says a lot about the layering and boundaries (or lack thereof) in your application

Comment: @kai I indeed use logging and configuration in many parts of my applications. I think that's normal. Also: insults, really?

Comment: @John it was not meant as an insult. I think that passing a repository accross several layers and down several levels of nested method calls is a code smell. It sounds like there are some issues with SRP and staying at an appropriate level of abstraction. I think a config shouldn't be passed from top to bottom, it should be read at the top and the results then govern what implementations and strategies are used at the bottom. Rarely should you actually let a class wander through your entire object graph.

Comment: @Kai Repositories are the weakest of the three examples in this case, but what's wrong with a piece of specialized code requesting a configuration provider that is set somewhere at the application root or in the unit test that tests the respective component?

Comment: @John it's a pretty large subject and I don't think we can do either side justice in the comments here. it basically comes down to code agility (as opposed to rigidness) and decoupling imo, but I'll just leave it at that, lest we run too far off topic.

Comment: @John: please answer my question: why don't you use **classes** to encapsulate the context of a group of functions?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to answer since the whole question is a comparison to using classes (ie constructor or member injection). Or maybe I don't get what you're asking?

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any other objections? Are there any legitimate, real-world reasons why DI with a static/global service locator would be bad?

Ugh, yes.

**Statics/globals are horrible.** They assume that the runtime of your application is homogenous - all of your instances require all the same sort of instances all over. That is naive. They interfere with concurrency, since any state in *any* of these things is inherently shared state. They interfere with testing, since you can't effectively mock different instances running concurrently or even different instances down the callstack. And then there's the usual debugging issues with global state.

**Hiding your problems is not fixing your problems.** If you have something that *everything* needs, then you have widespread coupling. If you have objects that need a bunch of dependencies, then you have widespread coupling. If you have a huge object hierarchy that makes it difficult to pass things around where they need to go, then you probably have a poor design. *DI does not fix these things!* All you're doing is hiding it behind some magic that passes dependencies around. You're not *removing* the dependencies, just making them less visible and a runtime error rather than a compile time error.

Comment: I'm not talking about a global state, I'm talking about  call contexts. Those are not shared accrosss threads (at most they are passed in the case of asynchronous programming), so there is no problem with concurrency. Providing mockups for testing is trivial, I've even given an example of how to do it (the code excerpt containing the `using`).

Comment: Further, I'm not talking about the case where *everything* needs something, but the case where *something* that is deeply nested in function calls need something.

Comment: Also, the removing of dependencies itself is indeed not explicitly talked about in my question, as I thought that's self-explanatory: You have `Dependency` be an interface. You can do that with the proposed method as well as contructor injection, so that's not really the issue here.

Comment: @john - Except that Call Contexts don't always flow along async calls. Either your dependencies go along to other threads (and you have shared state problems) or they don't (and you have missing dependency problems).

Comment: Of course they do, if they are properly implemented. `HttpContext.Current` in ASP.NET also flows accross async calls, even between threads.

Comment: @john - hmm, I might be misremembering then. There was some situation (perhaps OWIN?) where the call context didn't flow the entire way.

Comment: @Talastyn I know `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext` in the proper .NET framework does, but maybe you were using something else?

Comment: @john - nope that's the one. It's been a few months since it happened and I'm not able to recall the particulars. Still - I hate things like this that are hidden, and I doubly hate them when they're used to then hide other problems.

Comment: @John Call contexts are goddamn terrible. HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET is a blemish on the face of humanity that should be seared off with a laser beam. It's a hideously bad, lazy design that causes nothing but problems. HttpContext.Current is also not completely reliable (what a shocker!) we've had some cases in our controllers where we've had to hack around it missing once asynchronous controllers are involved. Not to mention that disgusting shit about ConfigureAwait(false). It's just terrible and broken and wrong.

Comment: @DeadMG Do you have a link to a source that makes the case of unreliability properly? (Not that a bug in ASP.NET was a indictment of call contexts.)

Comment: An exceedingly trivial Google produced exceedingly obvious results, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544272/httpcontext-current-is-null-in-an-asynchronous-callback

Comment: @DeadMG The guy doesn't give us the whole code, but it appears as if he's starting a background task that outlives the request. Obviously that can't possibly work. In a background task, you have no `HttpContext.Current` because there's no request.

Comment: @DeadMG Also, I don't like your tone. If it's so trivial to google, how come you weren't able to provide a proper example? How would you like it if I asked whether your problem with `HttpContext.Current` was merely a programming mistake as silly as the guy's you linked to was? You should be more sure before you go get bitchy.

Comment: @Talastyn FYI, I just discovered `System.Threading.AsyncLocal<T>` as an alternative to `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext`. I like that it doesn't deal with remoting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the benefit of dependency injection--that anything the class depends on is given to it, rather than assumed. What you're proposing is the *service locator* anti-pattern. There are a few cases where I might be tempted to use it (identity), but I'd prefer a clean contract for one reason--I never know how someone is going to use my code. I've seen this in my workplace, where someone designs code with ambient references to web concepts (like `HttpContext`) deep inside of a call chain instead of injecting it. A year or two later, and the code can't be reused in a console application because of the static dependencies. The same is true in trying to write unit tests.

- There's a dependency on `S1`

  - This isn't a fundamentalist objection, it's a failure to understand the point of dependency injection (which is different from preferring interfaces, which I think you're conflating with DI). Strings, integers, and lists should be passed in the constructor where they are needed. Your constructor should always expose the contract of the class--what requirements it has should be made clear and confirmed before the object is created. DI does not always use a DI container.
- Required dependencies should be explicit

  - See my response above about never knowing how the code will be used, especially in a library. Although it is verbose, that's the purpose--to accurately describe the contract. Adding dependencies shouldn't change signatures; new methods/classes should be introduced to obsolete the old ones. This is a core principle of *semantic versioning* and is a good way to do library development. As far as catching implicit dependencies, I'd rather catch something at compile time rather than receive an angry bug from a user.
- One shouldn't rely on magic

  - It's magic in the sense that your dependencies just appear, rather than be asked for. That's problematic when the dependency you get has special constraints on it (like HttpContext).

Here are some links to other discussions about the server locator anti-pattern and reasons to avoid it:

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0&feature=youtu.be

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-anti-pattern

Comment: You're missing my point about integers, strings and lists: Not even the most fanatical DI-enthusiasts are refraining from using *concrete* implementations of integers, strings and lists in their code - rather than just depending on interfaces that create and use them.

Comment: "Adding dependencies shouldn't change signatures" Adding a constructor or method parameter obviously changes the signature. Supplying the old one as well just means the dependency is optional, which isn't the case we're discussing.

Comment: Nothing about dependency injection says that you can't use concrete implementations. You're conflating it with the maxim *prefer interfaces*. Those are two separate ideas. You prefer interfaces where there is logic or an external resource (for the most part). Strings and integers are primitives--they have no logic. DTOs fall in the same boat. Lists can go either way--and Visual Studio will warn you to use IEnumerable<T> instead of List<T> when possible.

Comment: If the dependency isn't optional, then you should probably be rethinking your class. Chances are, it's doing too much. Introducing new dependencies to existing classes isn't supposed to be easy because you will have an impact on everything upstream. That being said, there's nothing wrong with creating a new class and marking the old one obsolete. Once that's done, it's legacy code. All bets about maintainability are off, so I could condone instantiation inside of it.

Comment: "Nothing about dependency injection says that you can't use concrete implementations" What? If a constructor takes a concrete implementation rather than an interface, how is the class not depending on the concrete implementation?

Comment: "Strings and integers are primitives--they have no logic." Language dependend, but generally the question isn't black and white. There is more primitive and more sophisticated.

Comment: The hint is in the phrase itself: *dependency* injection. You don't remove the fact that the class depends on something, you just make it explicit *what* those dependencies are and *how* they're resolved. If my constructor wanted nothing but concrete implementations, it's still a valid use of DI--even if it conflicts with other design principles. As for black and white answers, there are very few in programming. Service locator is a good example--bad in most cases, essential in a few.

Comment: What's to resolve when what you pass in is concrete? I thought the key words here was *injection*. Who is injecting anything when the class chooses what it depends on directly?

Comment: @John A dependency is a type that a class needs to refer to in order to do it's work. This can be a purely abstract interface, a concrete class, a simple struct or a primitive datatype. It is 100 % irrelevant and has exactly nothing at all to do with DI. DI is about HOW the class gains access to the dependency (by having it INJECTED by someone else, as opposed to grabbing it out of thin air without the knowledge of the client). You are mixing different SOLID principles together.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great idea partly because I had exactly the same idea myself. I know it is workable at least because I've done something very similar. I'd be very interested to see what other objections are raised.  As to the ones so far, I don't think they are substantial. The most interesting is within the http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ link.  In short it says that a third-party consumer of

```
SomeFunction()
```

may fail to set up the service locator as its not forced to do so whereas in the case

```
SomeFunction(dependency)
```

the compiler will force it to supply the dependency.  However I think having to supply the dependency in 3rd party code using SomeFunction is liable to be just as much of a problem as it is in the first party code.

In the case of a logger, you will have the classic chain reaction problem of introducing a parameter in a commonly used function.  The caller of the function has to find that parameter, commonly causing it to need the parameter itself, and so on, causing a large ripple effect up the call tree.  In the recommended context of using DI for a logger, the code change where you need to add logging to some function causes this need to add the logger service interface to the constructor of all classes up the chain from whereever the function is used.

This is a significant maintenance cost for DI in this use case, and potentially very difficult to manage.

This cost is not isolated to the codebase where the logger is required. In the example where SomeFunction is being used by a third party, it will also be more efficient to supply the logging service once to the service locator than to write it into the constructors of all the third party code that needs it too.

What this comes down to is does it ever make sense for a global context to exist?  The answer to that has to be yes as it makes data objects which are widely used at all levels of code much easier to access without creating large numbers of parameters to pass them around.

Comment: The fallacy about dependencies rippling all the way through the object graph just because one leaf node right at the bottom needed it is just plain wrong. If that happens, it's because you have no layering in your application. If a top-level controller needs to know about the dependencies of a small logic helper for some strategy object 20 levels down, then you have an ARCHITECTURAL problem, not a problem with DI. as has been pointed out many times: DI does not solve your dependency problems, it makes them VISIBLE (so you can fix them).

Comment: @kai I'm thinking of a code timer utility object which needs a logger service.  Anywhere I use that code timer I am supposed to introduce constructor parameters for the logger until I reach an object initialised at startup according to 'proper' DI, am I right?  It doesn't matter if it's 3 layers each time, that's a lot of maintenance.  But also I fail to see that its a design error to have a deep object tree if, say, I've got a complex domain model.  Are you of the view that in this case, the intermediate objects have some kind of dependency on the logger which DI is exposing?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with a deep object graph, but there IS something inherently wrong with a rigid object graph (where local changes propagate through the whole system). Given a dependency graph A -> B -> C where (->) denotes a dependency (A is top-level), then A should be totally oblivious to the existence of C. This is an age-old topic and the very core of dependency management. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle.

Comment: @kai I don't accept an opinion merely because there's a Wikipedia article on the matter, computer science is full of one fad after another that gets exaggerated by new waves of graduates thinking they know it all just because they read the latest book. When C uses a logger, logging must be configured. That happens at the root of the application (A), while the intermediate layers (B) are still oblivious to the dependency. That's the way all major logging frameworks are designed (nlog, log4, etc.). You're arguing the factory to create loggers should be passed around to make that explicit...

Comment: @kai ...even through layers of code that don't log themselves? Having dependencies explicit is sensible in those cases where they are part of business logic. If it's something extremely fundamental, such as logging, or .NETs ambient transactions or ASP.NET `HttpContext.Current`, it's not that sensible. In many cases, the the dependency is obvious. If I do databases, I know I have transactions. If I do web development, I know I have requests. That shouldn't surprise anybody. Clutter has it's downsides too, and I'm not only talking about the bleeding fingers.

Comment: the dependency inversion principle isn't some "new fad" that came up in the "latest books a bunch of graduates read", the term was coined in the 90's by Robert C Martin, and the whole notion of dependency management and dealing with abstractions is as old as the field of computer science itself. that's not the point of the article though, my point is that it seems to me like you have a skewed or wrong image of what dependency inversion IS, so I linked to a source where one can learn more about the subject, because it's more fit for a uni course than for a P.SE comment.

Comment: @JamesEllis-Jones - "Anywhere I use that code timer I am supposed to introduce constructor parameters for the logger until I reach an object initialised at startup according to 'proper' DI, am I right? It doesn't matter if it's 3 layers each time, that's a lot of maintenance."  -- No, that's wrong.  Any object that needs a logger should have the logger injected at its constructor call, which should be in the *top level construction module* or, at in the worst case where the objects need to be created dynamically *in a factory that is created by the top level module*.  There are no cases ...

Comment: ... where dependencies traverse multiple levels like that.  They are all created and passed through in a simple heirarchy of those two levels: top level and factory layer.  It *is* a design error to have more than 2 levels of business objects creating each other, because *it is difficult to understand where the dependencies come from*, it is also *difficult to replicate in a test scenario* and because *it is unnecessary to have any more than 2 such layers*.

Comment: @John "You're arguing the factory to create loggers should be passed around to make that explicit...  even through layers of code that don't log themselves?" No, because *that's not how you use dependency injection*.  When you use DI, you *centralise all dependency management and object creation* so that *no component needs to know about any other component's dependencies*, except for the dependency manager component (which may be your own custom object creation code or may be a DI framework... it doesn't matter).  See my previous 2 comments for more.

Comment: @Jules (and also I think @kai) you're confusing services, which in DI are created when a context is initialised (i.e. an application or in a web service, a request), and domain objects, which I can create whenever I like, and can have arbitrary chains of subobjects, any of which might need to do logging if they have any methods on them.  If you want to tell me I can only create 2 layers of business objects, you'd better have a reference because it sounds totally impractical and is nothing I've ever heard of.

Comment: @JamesEllis-Jones No, I'm not confusing anything.  If domain objects need anything injected, then they should be created in a factory that has the necessary dependencies available, rather than in locations scattered throughout your code.  That factory is then directly injected into the code that requires it, hence the 2-levels described.  If one business object can create another business object, it needs to know that business object's factory, *but no other dependencies of that business object*.

Comment: @Jules from what I've read, factories in DI are to be able to dynamically choose which service is created at runtime. If you try and solve this problem with them, you are just moving it to another place as you still have to pass a reference to the factory through the calling tree.

Comment: "factories in DI are to be able to dynamically choose which service is created at runtime" -- that's one purpose of factories.  A more general one is to decouple object creation from use, so that anything you need about the object that is used (including class, dependencies, or lifetime) can be varied.  "you still have to pass a reference to the factory through the calling tree" -- no, you don't, as the factory is a service that does not change at runtime so can be injected directly to the point of use rather than along the call chain.